# How do I disable all the onclick events on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Hi want to disable all onclick events on a page
i write this:

```
window.onclick = anyfunction;
document.onclick=anyfunction;
function anyfunction() {};
```

That's work but if page contain this code

```
$("body").click(function () { 
  anyfunctions();
});
```

It will run.
even i add

> document.body.onclick

Jquery code runs again.
I want to disable all onclick functions (java script and jquery and ... ) with javascript without using jquery library

Target is to block popup windows
Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible to achieve this

Comment: you need to write a lot of code to do this...my suggestion is to show transparent div to cover the whole page, but that will disable everything on your page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("*").unbind("click"); // Removes all click handlers added by javascript from every element
$("[onclick]").removeAttr("onclick"); // Finds all elements with an 'onclick' attribute, and removes that attribute
```

Comment: Thanks but i won't use jquery, any javascript code that do it?

Comment: Is there a way to add the click handlers back after doing this?

Answer (score 3):

This css may help you in a better way.

```
function disableEvents()
{
$('#divname').css('pointer-events','none');
}
```

call this function where ever and whenever you would like to stop the click events on your page. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try

```
$('*').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

also see - [How to prevent onclick statements from being executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771498/how-to-prevent-onclick-statements-from-being-executed)

and - [Prevent onclick action with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756425/prevent-onclick-action-with-jquery)