# How to disable the clicking of any element on the page after a jQuery click

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to disable the entire page by not allowing any further clicking anywhere on the page once already clicked. I'm aware there are so many sources with similar context, but didn't quite find any satisfying answer to my solution.

js:

```
  $("#link").on( "click", function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("div.container").css("opacity", 0.4);
    $("#loading").css("display","block");
});
```

With the above code I'm just able to grey out the page, but I also want to be able to disable any clicks on the page when greyed out.

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loading  {
background: url(../images/loading.png);
display: none;
margin: auto;
}
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: I think this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801713/how-do-i-disable-all-the-onclick-events-on-a-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about putting an overlay on top of your content?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").on( "click", function() {
        $(body).append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        $("#loading").show(); // sets css to display: block (can also use fadeIn()
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 100;
}
#loading {
    z-index: 101;
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/loading.png);
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought that's what you meant in the original post. Are you trying to only allow 1 click per link? Or are you trying to prevent the whole page from being clickable once an item is clicked?

Comment: im trying to prevent the whole page from clicking when the item has been clicked once...

Answer (score 0):

To disable the click function of any html element ( button , anchor, checbox etc ), just set `onclick = "return false"`

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>

$('a').attr("onclick","return false");
```